# Ocaml, implement freevars letrec using sets

Tags: set, ocaml, implementation, letrec

I'm trying to implement letrec using mathematical lambda notation for the function, but I'm having difficulty. My assignment says that let can be defined as

```
p(e1) U (p(e2) - {x})
```

and that letrec can be defined as

```
(p(e1) - {f x}) U (p(e2) - {f})
```

I've successfully implemented let to find freevars in an expression, but I'm struggling with letrec implementation:

```
let rec fv (e:expr) : S.t = match e with
  | Id name -> S.singleton name
  | Value x -> S.empty 
  | Lambda(name, body) ->  S.remove name (fv body)
  | Let(name, def, body) -> S.union (fv def) (S.diff (fv body) (S.singleton name))   

  | App (e1, e2) | Add (e1, e2) | Sub (e1, e2) | Mul (e1, e2) | Div (e1, e2) | Lt (e1, e2) | Eq (e1, e2) | And (e1, e2) -> S.union (fv e1) (fv e2)
```

Can someone please walk me through how to do this? Do I have to use Lambda? I'm pretty lost at this point and implementations just trying to follow the definition must have been done incorrectly on my part because I can't quite get it working.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question many times, I realized you're trying to calculate the free variables of an expression like this:

```
let rec x = e1 in e2
```

The essence of `let rec` is that appearances of `x` in `e1` are taken to refer to the value of `x` that is being defined. So `x` is not free in `e1`. And like the non-recursive `let`, `x` is not free in `e2` either. It's bound to the value `e1`.

So I would have thought the implementation would look like this:

```
(p(e1) - {x}) U (p(e2) - {x})
```

The definition you give doesn't make sense (to me), especially since there's no obvious meaning for `f`.

One could imagine restricting this form to cases where x is a function. Maybe that's what the assignment is telling you.

If you give a few more details, maybe someone a little more versed in these things can help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeffrey that there isn't quite enough information here. I'll give an implementation anyway, since the problem is fairly easy:

```
type term =
  | Var of string
  | App of term * term
  | Lam of string * term
  | Let of string * term * term
  | Letrec of (string * term) list * term

module S = Set.Make (String)

let rec free = function
  | Var name -> S.singleton name
  | App (f, x) -> S.union (free f) (free x)
  | Lam (arg, body) -> S.remove arg (free body)
  | Let (name, term, body) ->
    S.union (free term) (S.remove name (free body))
  | Letrec (rec_terms, body) ->
    S.diff
      (List.fold_left (fun set (_, term) ->
           S.union set (free term))
          (free body) rec_terms)
      (S.of_list (List.map fst rec_terms))
```

Note that this places no restriction on `rec` bound terms. If you will only be allowing functions there, then you can modify `term` to reflect that easily enough.